# Deprecated attempt to access property 'userAgent' on a non-Navigator object

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I am developing an app with ionic, cordova 4.3, angular and firebase.
When i run my app on ios i get always those two messages:

```
Deprecated attempt to access property 'userAgent' on a non-Navigator object.
Deprecated attempt to access property 'language' on a non-Navigator object.
```

I have read around and cordova should have solved the problem with the 3.7 version but it doesn't look like that.
I think the second one is when i try to read the language of the browser but i don't understand the first one.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think 3.7 fixed it for iOS 7, but then it didn't "Stay Fixed" on iOS8. Seems like it doesn't effect execution, so the word on the street is that everyone is ignoring it.  Doesn't seem like an answer, I agree, but just my two cents.

Comment: the problem was on iOS 8 and was solved for iOS 8 on cordova 3.7, maybe they broke something and the problem came back